# How I create build and deploye path for gitlab CI CD?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My project folder

- api
- frontend

Build and deploye successful but no any effect on website so
i need to set frontend path in my yml file..but how it possible that i don't know

Anyone help me?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
variables:
  ARTIFACT_NAME: my-cookbook.tgz
  DEV_BUCKET: dev-account-devops
  PROD_BUCKET: prod-account-devops
  S3_PATH: elk/${ARTIFACT_NAME}-${CI_BUILD_ID}-${CI_BUILD_REF}
package:
  stage: build
  script: git archive --format tgz HEAD > $ARTIFACT_NAME
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
    expire_in: 1 week
deploy_development:
  stage: deploy
  script:
   - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=$DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY
   - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$DEV_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
   - aws s3 cp $ARTIFACT_NAME s3://$DEV_BUCKET/$S3_PATH
  environment: development
deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
   - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=$PROD_AWS_ACCESS_KEY
   - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$PROD_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
   - aws s3 cp $ARTIFACT_NAME s3://$PROD_BUCKET/$S3_PATH
  environment: production
  when: manual
  only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 0):

*[The OP answered their own question in the linked [Forum Post](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/using-multiple-aws-accounts-for-deploy/7242) that was replaced with the `.yml` file in the question. The answer is copied here so that this question has an answer.]*

The export for the AWS Access Key had a typo and was missing the last bit. It should be `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` not `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`.